# Report Item has no value when only Group Row Total goes to new page in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have designed a SSRS reports which is based on Some grouping.
Every things working fine as assumptions. There is small problem when my Group row total goes to next page the Reports Item has no value .
I have some text boxes in Page header which expression contains reportitem value.
[image]

[image]

Please suggest any solution regarding this.

Regards
Ashish Bisht

Comment: What are the expressions you are using to populate the header text boxes?

Comment: ReportItems!RPT_INV_Date.Value
Same type of expression for other control.

Comment: Are the Report Items in question (RPT_INV_Date and the 'other') both unique to the report?  It looks as if so based on the generic nature of the address.  If that is the case, you can set up two parameters with those values and base the text boxes on those. Something like this:
Cstr(Parameters!StartDt.Value)
Your text boxes will need to be in a header (or footer) to use parameters, but they are useable on every page regardless of other data.  IIRC anyway.  If that's not an option, please post more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find the solution my own. I have inserted a new group row below the Total row and keeping it as hide every time and put some text box which value we need to Access in Page header text box.I have added some text boxes in Page header also which value we are setting with new row text box value. We are showing optional text box if Report item value has nothing other wise it will show.

Thanks